# Multiple Operations on Multiple Sets (Tables) in Aerospike cluster

Tags: java, workflow, crud, pseudocode, aerospike

**Current system state:**

Currently, I maintain three sets (tables, equivalent in RDBMS) in my aerospike namespace (database, equivalent in RDBMS) backed by RESTful service.

**Use-case:**

I want to perform CRUD operations on at least one set and sometimes at most on all sets based on some bulk inputs into my system.

**Expectation:**

I want to perform all these CRUD operations in an atomic manner *(means either all happen or none. This also contains an edge-case where some sets are successfully updated with their respective latest updates, and later on even a single set is un-successful. I would want to rollback my data to the previous state in each set.)*

**My workaround:**

1. First I tried to find the equivalent of [InsertOnSubmit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.table-1.insertonsubmit?view=netframework-4.8) in aerospike to use the approaches explained on this [answer of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762930/what-is-the-best-practice-for-inserting-or-updating-multiple-tables-at-once), but seems like that doesn't exist.
2. Second, I thought of creating an intermediate rollback workflow module. Psuedo code shown below:

   1. Temporarily save the new data in some data-type segregated set-wise.
   2. Loop through set-wise data, and pick the primary key from them and get the older data from aerospike and save it into some other data-type again segregated set-wise.
   3. Loop through all the sets one-by-one from first data-type and start performing CRUD operation accordingly. `IF[everything runs till the end]: GOTO step 6; ELSE: GOTO step 4`.
   4. Start rolling-back by looping through all the sets one-by-one from second data-type and start performing CRUD operation. `IF[everything runs till the end]: GOTO step 7; ELSE: GOTO step 5`.
   5. Log the error including all the details and report this error to alert system. Someone will get paged for it to have a look. `GO TO step 7;`
   6. Terminate, operation successful.
   7. Terminate, operation un-successful.

**Help Needed:**

1. Is there any chance to incoperate `InsertOnSubmit` behaviour on Aerospike cluster without creating my own roll-back workflow?
2. If not, then is there any better way to optimize my second approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - No. Aerospike offers atomicity only at a single record level. While inserting Master record and then replicating its copy to another node do follow true 2-phase commit semantics in Aerospike's Strong Consistency (SC) mode, any multi-record transaction has to be implemented at the application level.

2 - Any scheme implementing multi-record transactions, such as one you are thinking of, typically involves - creating some kind of "lock" bin in a record that you set, do the multi-record updates, build a before and after state of your data, have some kind of a maximum time to complete so you can rollback and clear abandoned operations and lock by the client application. Any of these schemes will only work reliably under Aerospike's Strong Consistency mode.

Comment: Thanks, @pgupta for your insights. I have a few quick questions:

1. What do you mean by "Mater record"?
2. I think the "lock" bin feature already exists on aerospike. Based on this discussion: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/record-level-locking-and-latency/5181.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) In Aerospike, records are distributed across 4096 partitions. There are `replication-factor` copies of each partition in a stable cluster. Each partition has one 'master' copy which is responsible for receiving all inserts/updates for records it contains. By 'master record' pgupta is indicating a copy of the record that exists on the master partition (i.e. not a read-only partition).
Note: Partition Masters aren't static, a new master can be promoted if the current master goes away. But the ordering is deterministically random based on the node-ids in the cluster.

Comment: 2) The lock you mention locks a single record during a single transaction. At this time, there isn't any builtin mechanism for multi-record transactions, general or otherwise. Often the need for multi-record transactions can be modeled away but there are some usages where it cannot. In distributed systems, coordination between cluster nodes comes with a significant performance tax - a general multi-record transaction solution will require coordination. For scaling, it is best to evaluate if you can model out such requirements.

Comment: By lock bin, I mean in a multi-record transaction implementation, you take one  record in your model and in it you designate a bin - name it "lockBin" - you enter 1 when some client is doing a multi-record transaction, starting with this record and involving multiple other records, and then the client sets it back to 0, freeing it to be used by another client.  You are implementing all this locking/freeing/freeing if locking client dies - all in the application. Aerospike does not natively support multi-record transactions. You cannot do this reliably without using Strong Consistency mode.